# Backgound images not displaying in IE 8 but working fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS for my background image.

```css
#container {
    background:url(images/Background.jpg);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1400px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
```

It's working totally fine in all other browsers apart from IE8, when the pages loads it's just a white background on IE.

If i was to give it a color background i.e #90F it would work totally fine, just the image.

Any Suggestions?

Regards

Comment: This is a tricky one with no definitive answer. I'd start with taking overflow:auto; and margin:auto; and stick a float:left in to see if they have any impact. If so, just put the removed styles one by one back in and see what  (or combination of styles) causes the image to not to appear. Then look for solutions for those specific combinations.

Answer (score 1):

put the URL in double quote like "images/Background.jpg" and close your style declaration with "}" -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        background:url("images/Background.jpg");
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1400px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Further you can check out this URL to the correct way to include background image - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-background.php

Comment: Still getting the white background :(

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct URL. You can check with the firebug whether image is loading or not.

Comment: it's working fine in firefox mate it's just IE which is causing this white background issue. If i was to give it a background instead if an image it will look fine

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem, where i had background image was in white letters and it was not displaying in IE8 (it got displayed but moved down to place where i have background color as white) ,where as it got displayed in other browsers well, i resolved by putting `display:inline-block`, you can try this. one reason will be the "container" might not have enough space to display the image,where it is supposed to be, and it will relocate to some other place, you can check this by putting `border: 2px solid black.` i would rather recommend to have proper width ,height and floating values to avoid these issues in future.

Comment: would you place that in the container?

Comment: background:url("images/Background.jpg");
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1400px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        display: inline-block; float:right/left;
        border: 2px solid black; float param either have right or left or inherit

Comment: tired that dude and still the same result apart from seeing the back border

Comment: where is black border coming, is it there where you expected to be?

Comment: Yes 100% border is where it should be

Comment: so image is not loading?

Comment: can you try this, if you want <div id="Container">
  <img  src="images/Background.jpg" alt="image"/>
</div>, see what happens

Comment: The image displays in the top left corner and pushing everything down, but the image is there now

Comment: its very hard to answer , without seeing your layout , i think you need to clear the divs below, you can add clear :right/left/both in below containers i mean , the containers which are placed below image container.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is not case-sensitive though other browsers are.

Because other browsers are loading the image I presume that you not only got the image URL correct though the case-sensitivity of it correct as well.

You have not posted the use of `background-position`, I recommend using it.

Examples...

```
background-position: center center;

background-position: left center;

background-position: 10% center;

background-position: 10% 20%;
```

IE on Mac will not load CSS assets (cursors, images, etc) if you use quotes. If you do use quotes in CSS use single-quotes only.

Comment: How dude, I'm a still a novice when it comes to this, so what position should this be?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position and I edited in some quick examples.